# Code conversion from C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

Hello all i have tried to convert c# code to vb but getting error in this line as "Expression Expected" what can be the error and what is the correct syntax. Error is in second line

```
Dim m As MenuItem = TryCast(sender, MenuItem)
audioDevice = (If(m.Index>0, filters.AudioInputDevices(m.Index-1), Nothing))
```

C# CODE

```
MenuItem m = sender as MenuItem;
audioDevice = ( m.Index>0 ? filters.AudioInputDevices[m.Index-1] : null );
```

Comment: post your C# code too

Comment: Maybe `If` must be `Iif`?

Comment: @nathan742 Noooo - never use `IIf` !!

Comment: As per MSDN, your code must be working properly on VS2008 and up http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985(v=vs.90).aspx If you do not want to use `Iif` then your choice...

Comment: @nathan IIf will cause the code to crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim m As MenuItem = TryCast(sender, MenuItem)
audioDevice = (IIf(m.Index>0, filters.AudioInputDevices(m.Index-1), Nothing))
```

[IIf Function MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

As IIf Function is deprecated use like this

```
If m.Index>0 Then
    audioDevice = filters.AudioInputDevices(m.Index-1)
  Else
    audioDevice = Nothing
  End If
```

**[Sample](http://net-informations.com/vbprj/programflow/vb-iif.htm)**

Hope it helps

Comment: that's what I've said

Comment: @nathan742 Yup you are right in comments, but i too found out that it might be mistake and  i was in search of online documentation of it..

Comment: Iif is deprecated in favor of If

Comment: see he was asking where the error may be, i pointed out that.

Answer (score 4):

Are you running VB.Net 2008 or later? The `If` operator is not supported in earlier versions.

Since the non-short-circuit `Iif` function will cause the true-part of the expression to cause an index out of range, you should use an `If Then Else` statement if you want a version prior to 2008 to be supported.

Comment: Also note that the `IF` operator is type safe whereas `IIF` is not.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, IIF is not an operator, it is a function.  IF in newer versions of VB is an operator.

Answer (score -1):

Here is probably the best tool I have ever found! And having been a developer for over 10 years, when I found this (And with most examples online being in C, this was just GOLDEN!) .. Hope this helps you! (And anyone else that hasn't stumbled across this 'gem'... Finally VB coders have better access to online examples... NOTE*  this isn't the only code converter, but it's by far the best one I have ever used.. Perhaps if you convert the code again using this, your troubles might be solved.......

http://converter.telerik.com/   (Does an amazing job on converting)